# Proving Limit Involving The Difference Between Rational & Irrational Numbers

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Using the formal definition of limit, formally show that for any irrational number $V$, $$\lim_{x\to V} f(x) = 0$$ where the function $f$ is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ with the following definition $$f(x)
  = \begin{cases}0, &x\text{ is irrational} \\ \frac{1}{q},
    &\frac{p}{q} = x\text{ is rational}\end{cases}$$ and $\frac{p}{q}$
  has no common factor (i.e., $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{2}{7}$ instead of
    something like $\frac{4}{14}$ or $\frac{5}{10}$).

My solution goes as follows:

$\begin{align*}
      &\;\forall V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: \lim_{x\to V} f(x) = 0 \\
      \leftrightarrow&\;\forall V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta > 0: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: 0 < |x - V| < \delta \to |f(x)| < \epsilon \\
\leftrightarrow&\;\forall V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta > 0: \begin{cases}\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}: 0 < |x - V| < \delta \to |f(x)| < \epsilon \\ 
\forall x \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: 0 < |x - V| < \delta \to |f(x)| < \epsilon
\end{cases} \\
\leftrightarrow&\;\forall V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta > 0: \begin{cases}\forall x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}: 0 < \left|\frac{p}{q} - V\right| < \delta \to \left|\frac{1}{q}\right| < \epsilon \\ 
\forall x \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: 0 < |x - V| < \delta \to 0 < \epsilon
\end{cases} \\
    \end{align*}$

Since $0 < \epsilon$ is always true when $\epsilon > 0$, my focus then shifts on determining $\delta$ on the following case:

$\begin{align*}
&\;\forall V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta > 0: \forall x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}: 0 < \left|\frac{p}{q} - V\right| < \delta \to \left|\frac{1}{q}\right| < \epsilon \\
\leftrightarrow&\;\forall V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}: \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists\delta > 0: \forall x = \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}: 0 < \left|\frac{p}{q} - V\right| < \delta \to \left|\frac{1}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{K} \leq \epsilon \\
    \end{align*}$

The proposition above will be false when $1 \leq |q| \leq K \in \mathbb{N}$.

My difficulty is then on deciding the value of $\delta$ based on $V \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $1 \leq |q| \leq K$, the following proposition is always false for any $p \in \mathbb{Z}$: $$0 < \left|\frac{p}{q} - V\right| < \delta$$

Anyone well versed in Number Theory perhaps can give me some help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any irrational number $V$, and any positive integer $q$, there will be at most $q+1$ values of $p$ such that $\left|\dfrac{p}{q}-V\right| \le \dfrac{1}{2}$. So, there are at most $\displaystyle\sum_{q = 1}^{K}(q+1)$ rationals $\dfrac{p}{q}$ such that $\left|\dfrac{p}{q}-V\right| \le \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $1 \le q \le K$.

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{q = 1}^{K}(q+1)$ is a finite number, $\min \left\{\left|\dfrac{p}{q}-V\right| : 1 \le q \le K, \left|\dfrac{p}{q}-V\right| \le \dfrac{1}{2} \right\}$ is guaranteed to exist, and is greater than $0$ since $\left|\dfrac{p}{q}-V\right| > 0$ for all rationals $\dfrac{p}{q}$ and irrationals $V$. So, simply pick $\delta$ smaller than this minimum you are done.

Comment: Any link/pointer to the proof that for any irrational number $V$, and any positive integer $q$, there will be at most $q + 1$ values of $p$ such that $\left|\frac{p}{q}-V\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: If $|\frac{p}{q}-V| \le \frac{1}{2}$, then $V - \frac{1}{2} \le \frac{p}{q} \le V + \frac{1}{2}$, and so, $(V-\frac{1}{2})q \le p \le (V+\frac{1}{2})q$. How many integers can lie in an interval of length $q$?